# fluid template: passing a javascript varible as the argument value?

Tags: javascript, typo3, fluid

For a f:link show action in my fluid list template i want to pass a javascript variable to the arguments, basically the uid (to pass that specific object to the showAction), but it doesn't work the way i intend to do it. Is there a workaround for this particular problem?

The naked template looks like this:

```
  <f:for each="{termins}" as="termin"> 
    <tr>
      <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{termin : termin}"> {termin.mitarbeiter}</f:link.action></td>
      <td><f:link.action action="show" arguments="{termin : termin}"> {termin.kunde}</f:link.action></td>
    </tr>
  </f:for>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - and you also can't (read: never should) generate links to controller actions from JS since it needs to generate a security checksum. Modifying the URL you create will generate a security error. The checksum exists to prevent DDOS so it has good reason.

There are two options:

- You can generate all links in advance
- You can make a link-generating service that you call with XHR to generate the necessary links from JS.

Only the first one is appropriate to your use case. Especially so since you want to pass UID values which always refer to an object in the database - which means you can easily generate a list of links to all possible detail views, then read/pass that list of links from your JS to select the right one.

Comment: As my extension will not be accessible for the general public, is it possible to deactivate the security checksum?

Comment: Before you even consider that, you should read these two links very, very carefully. You would be opening yourself to a real security problem that's been fixed for many years and is very likely to be used as attack vector. https://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash and https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/network/vulnerability/typo3-chash-parsing-denial-of-service-vulnerability/. Now that you've read the warnings on those links, and you know why you *shouldn't'* do this, you can look up `cHashExcludedParameters` in documentation and TYPO3 install tool if you must.

Answer (score 0):

The JS is something working after the fluid template. The right order is, your fluid template is parsed into the HTML, and then the browser render the HTML/JS/CSS to you. So, you can not expect to use JS value in your fluid template.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1) Instead of a link use a form and transmit it via POST. Set a form field dynamically with JavaScript. That way your variable isn't included in the (cHash-) checksum.

2) Create an AJAX action that accepts your variable as argument. Let it generate a valid link. Use POST to call it with your variable data. Show the link on your page with JavaScript.